# How can I get Windows 7 to detect my Belinea 10 20 05 monitor?

Tags: windows-7, display

Using an HP monitor. The laptop requires VGA and the monitor uses DVI-D so I'm using a converter.

When I try to detect the monitor from the control panel it doesn't detect anything. The monitor always displays "no signal".

There doesn't seem to be any suitable driver available on the Belinea site. I tried installing the closest driver I could find but that didn't work either.

Comment: Which converter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You're sure it's a DVI-D to VGA converter rather than just a dongle or adapter?  DVI-D does NOT carry analog (unlike DVI-A and DVI-I) so you need an active converter box.

Comment: Aha! I think it is just a dongle. I'll get an active converter box and mark this as the correct answer if it works. Thanks very much!